# Disable a loading of specific war in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web, war

Is there any configuration available in tomcat,that i need to disable to specific war from loading.

Regards,

Raghavan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `server.xml` look for `Host` element. Add to it the `deployIgnore` attribute with an appropriate value.
The value is

> A regular expression defining paths to ignore when autoDeploy and deployOnStartup are set.
>   ...
>   This regular expression is relative to appBase. It is also anchored, meaning the match is performed against the entire file/directory name.
>   So, foo matches only a file or directory named foo but not foo.war, foobar, or myfooapp.
>   To match anything with "foo", you could use .*foo.*.

So for example you could specify something like

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" deployIgnore="yourApp(.war)?"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    ...        
</Host>
```

See [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html).